# Counting the number of times each pattern in a file appears in a separate file

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to scan a file (test.txt), something like this:

```
make
bake
baker
makes
take
cook
sbake
```

for patterns listed in a separate file (ref.txt):

```
ake
make
bake
look
```

I have tried looping with grep like so:

```
while read seq; do grep -c "$seq" test.txt; done > out.txt < ref.txt
```

However, it doesn't count partial matches only exact matches (or inconsistent in counting partial matches) and I output:

```
4
1
2
0
```

instead of

```
6
2
3
0
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: sorry, edited above so should be correct now

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. To me it correctly returns 6 2 3 0.

Comment: Same here, cannot be reproduced on `grep (GNU grep) 2.26`

Comment: thanks, looks like there must be a glitch with the grep I am using, I'll try a different method without grep

Comment: It's much more likely your input files contain trailing control-Ms (and so `ake^M` cannot match `baker^M` since there's no `^M` between `bake` and `r^M`) than that your grep is broken. `cat -v file` will show the control-Ms then try running dos2unix or similar on your input files then try a solution again.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to this sort of coding and its the little things in unix I guess that cause lots of issues

Comment: That's not a UNIX issue, it's a Windows issue. For reasons beyond mortal ken Windows tools use `\r\n` for "newline" instead of just `\n`. UNIX uses `\n` for the obvious reason that there's no point throwing in spurious extra characters. So if you have a file that was created in Windows and you try to run UNIX tools on it then you have to first get rid of the redundant `\r`s (or with GNU awk set `RS='\r\n'`) or they're just considered part of the data that comes before the newline.

Answer (score 1):

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the reasons not to try to do this with a shell loop.

The standard UNIX tool for manipulating text is awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$0]=0;next} {for (re in cnt) cnt[re]+=gsub(re,"&")} END{for (re in cnt) print re, cnt[re]}' ref.txt test.txt
ake 6
bake 3
look 0
make 2
```

The above assumes the text in your ref.txt file doesn't contain any regexp metacharacters or if it does then a regexp match is desirable. If it can but you need a string instead of regexp match, you'd need a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ while read -r line; do grep -c $line test.txt ; done < ref.txt
6
2
3
0
```